# Find a basis of linear subspaces intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am solving an exercise about linear subspaces, I would find a basis of the [image] with
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I found that V is a span of the vector 1 (because is linearly dependet), I am in trouble with reduction of [image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Crostul I need to find a basis for the intersection of 2 subspaces

Comment: well think about it. If V just spans a line as a subspace and W spans a plane, you just have to check if the line is on the plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that $v_2=2v_1$ and $v_1=w_1+w_2$.